# Chinese Poem Crossword Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, language, crosswords

Hiii
Here is a crossword puzzle about Poems!
[image]

1: Do you love me?
2: Mid-autumn barbecue
3: Ching Ming so many rain
4: Ghosts come from rain, Emperors come from clouds
5: I want to beat west
6: Eight thousand miles
7: Qin and Han
8: Pine trees. Moon?

Please give an upvote if you like it ;)

Comment: is 4 missing a grid?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: It should be 七言律詩

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combined work with credits:

> 1) 東邊日出西邊雨，道是無晴還有晴 (me)
>  2) 壚邊人似月 (me)
>  3) 清明時節雨紛紛 (Simon-Nail-It)
>  4) 紛紛雨外靈均過，瑟瑟雲中帝子歸 (me)
>  5) 不破樓蘭終不還 (me)
>  6) 八千里路雲和月 (jafe)
>  7) 秦時明月漢時關 (Simon-Nail-It)
>  8) 明月松間照 (Simon-Nail-It)

Grid:

> [image]

Comment: @KSharing is 1) 还 or 却？Thanks!

Comment: The answer should be 還 :)

Comment: this is done, can you pls green-check this answer?

Answer (score 3):

Partial since I'll have no chance of getting all of these... I think #6 is

> "[八千里路云和月](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%AB%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8C%E8%B7%AF%E9%9B%B2%E5%92%8C%E6%9C%88)"

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 3):

I will keep update my answer when I find more answer but here is my partial answer.

> 3)清明时节雨纷纷 
>  7)秦时明月汉时关 
>  8)明月松间照

Update: I'm not sure for this one buf I think based of Jafe answer

> 2)秋边一雁声

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: 2 is acceptable but it is not my initial answer